# Openocd reports "Failed with code (1)" for eclipse debugging a STM32F429 Discovery board

Tags: eclipse, arm, stm32, openocd

When I start a debugging session under eclipse (luna) for my STM32F429 Discovery board. I get the following error:

OpenOCD failed with code (1).

The information in the console pane is:

Open On-Chip Debugger 0.9.0-dev-00223-g1567cae (2015-01-12-13:43)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.sourceforge.net/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
adapter speed: 2000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst
Started by GNU ARM Eclipse
Info : clock speed 2000 kHz
Error: open failed
in procedure 'init' 
in procedure 'ocd_bouncer' 
in procedure 'transport'
in procedure 'init'

The "board" file being referenced in the debug setup is: stm32f429discovery.cfg

I did have this working for another ST-Micro board and I could do a full debug session with no problems. Suddenly it just stopped being able to access the board and I get the same errors for it as I get with this board.

I was hoping to be able to use the purely open source s/w that runs on Linux to be able to work with these boards. I'm hoping that someone can get me out of this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

What you use the command and debugger?

**try:**

`openocd -f interface/jlink.cfg -f target/stm32f429discovery.cfg`